# Using Babel-like shorthands in ConTeXt

Tags: context, babel, cyrillic, shorthands

I'm new to ConTeXt, and I feel very excited about its capabilities. But as soon as I've tried to make a handsome document in Russian, I've learned that ConTeXt doesn't seem to provide Babel-shorthands as (Lua/Xe/pdf)LaTeX have used to:

```
% pdfLaTeX code
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
"--* Прямая речь "--- "<после "`тире"' неразрывный пробел">.    
\end{document}
```

The code above contains a direct speech dash, a Cyrillic em-dash and two types of quote marks, and produces:
[image: pdfLaTeX code]

Unsurprisingly, ConTeXt recognizes none of those shorthands:

```
% ConTeXt code
\mainlanguage[russian]
\setupbodyfont[libertine]
\starttext
"--* Прямая речь "--- "<после "`тире"' неразрывный пробел">.
\stoptext
```

[image: ConTeXt code]

While quote marks can be substituted with corresponding font characters (« » „ ‟) , the specific Cyrillic dash `"---` (which is shorter than em-dash, and has fixed spaces around it with non-breaking one at left side) can't be, and I've yet to figure out a way of typing or implementing it.

Is there a way of enabling Babel shorthands or implementing their functionality in ConTeXt?

(Thanks and Happy New Year!)

**UPD1**: I've found that a nicer way to define `\cyrdash` symbol would be something like

```
\define\cyrdash{\scale[sx=0.9]{---}} % produces a smoother dash
```

Also here's how `"---` is defined in Babel:

```
\def\@Acdash{\ifdim\lastskip>\z@\unskip\nobreak\hskip.2em\fi
  \cyrdash\hskip.2em\ignorespaces}%
```

**UPD2**: I was able to recreate the desired behavior with `translate` module:

```
\define\cyrdash{\scale[sx=0.80]{---}}  % Cyrillic dash sign

\usemodule[translate]
\translateinput["---][\unskip\thinspace\cyrdash\thinspace\ignorespaces] % Cyrillic text em-dash
\translateinput["--*][\leavevmode\cyrdash\hskip.35em] % Cyrillic direct speech dash

\mainlanguage[russian]
\setupbodyfont[dejavu]
\starttext\enableinputtranslation 
"--* Прямая речь "--- \quotation{после \quote{тире} неразрывный пробел}.    
\stoptext
```

[image: ConTeXt code with translate module]

(Many thanks to @Aditya for suggestions)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the quotes, you can either use:

```
\quotation{после \quote{тире} неразрывный пробел}.
```

or (as you note) directly type:

```
«после „тире” неразрывный пробел».
```

Here is a minimal example:

```
\mainlanguage[ru]
\setupbodyfont[dejavu]
\starttext
\quotation{после \quote{тире} неразрывный пробел}.    

«после „тире” неразрывный пробел».
\stoptext
```

which gives:

[image]

For the em-dashes, you can use compound words: `|<|` and `|=|`. By default, they do not leave any space, but that can be modified as follows:

```
\define\cyrdash{\hbox to.8em{--\hss--}}
\unprotect
\setuplanguage
  [\s!ru]
  [
    \c!midsentence=\cyrdash,
    \c!leftsentence=\cyrdash,
    \c!rightsentence=\cyrdash,
  ]
\def\beginofsubsentencespacing{\thinspace}
\def\endofsubsentencespacing{\thinspace}

% Redefine |=|
\definetextmodediscretionary =
  {\endofsubsentencespacing\prewordbreak\midsentence\beginofsubsentencespacing\prewordbreak} 
\protect

\mainlanguage[ru]
\setupbodyfont[dejavu]

\starttext
|=|Прямая речь|<|\quotation{после \quote{тире} неразрывный пробел}.    
\stoptext
```

which gives

[image]

**EDIT**: Depending on the exact definitions that you want, you can redefine `|<|` and `|=|` (or even create new ones instead of `<` and `=`). For example:

```
\define\cyrdash{\dontleavehmode\scale[sx=0.80]{---}}  
% Redefine |=|
\definetextmodediscretionary =
  {\leavevmode\cyrdash\hskip.35em}

% Redefine |<|
\definetextmodediscretionary <
  {\removeunwantedspaces\thinspace\cyrdash\thinspace\ignorespaces}
```

Note that `\thinspace` is defined (roughly) as: `\kern<amount>`, so it is unbreakable. If you want breakable space, use `\hskip<amount>`.

Comment: As the example shows, `"---` typesets a shorter dash than the em-dash, with thin (non-breaking) spaces on either side; with `"--*` the same dash is used, but only spaced at the right.

Comment: @egreg: See my updated answer. I copied the definition of `\cyrdash` from another answer; I am guessing that the spaces should be `\thinspace`; if not, that can be changed appropriately.

Comment: @Aditya thank you very much, great take on quotes, but this modified compound word thing still doesn't leave the space? And also I was a bit wrong: `"---` has a fixed non-breaking space at its left and _breakable_ fixed space (of the same width) at its right. Could you modify the code accordingly, please?

Comment: @Aditya: I've figured that `|=|` does seem to behave like `"---`. Did you mean using `|<|` as `"--*` and `|=|` as `"---`?

Comment: @Aditya: also `|=|` doesn't seem to suppress source whitespaces (which might be inconvenient). I've updated the question with implementation of this dash in babel, I hope that might be helpful.

Comment: @The_Keeper: See my updated answer, where I copy your definitions

Comment: @Aditya: wow, there are so many different commands in ConTeXt! What do you think about my own answer below? isn't it too a 'dirty trick'? I'm ready to post it as UPD2, and mark your answer as accepted

Comment: @The_Keeper: If you want to stick to the babel shortcuts, your answer is fine. I do not consider to be a too dirty a trick.